# unicode error while zipfile extract

Tags: python, zip, python-unicode

I have a little script which shall extract a .zip-file.
This works well, but only for .zip-files which doesn't contain files with letters like "ä", "ö", "ü" (and so on) in their filenames.
Otherwise I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.pyc", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "install.py", line 92, in run
  File "zipfile.pyc", line 962, in extractall
  File "zipfile.pyc", line 950, in extract
  File "zipfile.pyc", line 979, in _extract_member
  File "ntpath.pyc", line 108, in join
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the extracting part of my script:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(path1)
zip.extractall(path2)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is `path1`? Is it a unicode value or a bytestring?

Comment: What is your Python Version?

Comment: path1 = os.getcwd()+'\\..\\'+myfile # myfile = 'test.zip', python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one suggestion:

I get the error when I do that:

```
>>> c = chr(129)
>>> c + u'2'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    c + u'2'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

There is a unicode string passed to join somewhere.

Could it be the file path of the zipfile is encoded in unicode?
What if you do this:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(str(path1))
zip.extractall(str(path2))
```

or this:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(unicode(path1))
zip.extractall(unicode(path2))
```

This is line 128 in ntpath:

```
def join(a, *p): # 63
    for b in p: # 68
                path += "\\" + b  # 128
```

Second Suggestion:

```
from ntpath import *

def join(a, *p):
    """Join two or more pathname components, inserting "\\" as needed.
    If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
    will be discarded."""
    path = a
    for b in p:
        b_wins = 0  # set to 1 iff b makes path irrelevant
        if path == "":
            b_wins = 1

        elif isabs(b):
            # This probably wipes out path so far.  However, it's more
            # complicated if path begins with a drive letter:
            #     1. join('c:', '/a') == 'c:/a'
            #     2. join('c:/', '/a') == 'c:/a'
            # But
            #     3. join('c:/a', '/b') == '/b'
            #     4. join('c:', 'd:/') = 'd:/'
            #     5. join('c:/', 'd:/') = 'd:/'
            if path[1:2] != ":" or b[1:2] == ":":
                # Path doesn't start with a drive letter, or cases 4 and 5.
                b_wins = 1

            # Else path has a drive letter, and b doesn't but is absolute.
            elif len(path) > 3 or (len(path) == 3 and
                                   path[-1] not in "/\\"):
                # case 3
                b_wins = 1

        if b_wins:
            path = b
        else:
            # Join, and ensure there's a separator.
            assert len(path) > 0
            if path[-1] in "/\\":
                if b and b[0] in "/\\":
                    path += b[1:]
                else:
                    path += b
            elif path[-1] == ":":
                path += b
            elif b:
                if b[0] in "/\\":
                    path += b
                else:
                    # !!! modify the next line so it works !!!
                    path += "\\" + b
            else:
                # path is not empty and does not end with a backslash,
                # but b is empty; since, e.g., split('a/') produces
                # ('a', ''), it's best if join() adds a backslash in
                # this case.
                path += '\\'

    return path

import ntpath
ntpath.join = join
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use your second suggestion a bit more?  I don't understand where I would use the join you posted.

Answer (score 3):

For portable reason, maybe you zip files from Windows and extract them in Linux, you can convert all the file's path to unicode in zipped file, when extract from zip, *do not* use `ZipFile.extractall`, this default extract file to disk and do not support unicode path in zipped file, try this:

```
import zipfile, sys, os,
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for m in zf.infolist():
    data = zf.read(m) # extract zipped data into memory
    # convert unicode file path to utf8
    disk_file_name = m.filename.encode('utf8')
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(disk_file_name)
    try:
        os.makedirs(dir_name)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == os.errno.EEXIST:
            pass
        else:
            raise
    except Exception as e:
        raise

    with open(disk_file_name, 'wb') as fd:
        fd.write(data)
zf.close()
```

Comment: This is what fixed my issue. But I am not quite sure why the issue occurred in first place. I zipped file on linux only and on trying to unzip using python it gave the error but there were many other zipped files where I didn't face this issue. Could you tell the reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

Clear as water: The message states that the *ASCII* decoder can't handle *non-ASCII* characters. You have to select some other character encoding.

Comment: When concatenating Python byte strings and unicode values, Python automatically attempts to decode the byte string to unicode. You cannot control that process when it happens in library code. This isn't a cut-and-dry problem.